# Problem of writing scilab code on a project - Morris-Lecar model

Tags: r, homework

This is a computational neuroscience project. We are asked to plot the Morris-Lescar model (question 3 below).

The model should be plotted with scilab or R.

however, I don't know where to start? For the moment, the problem is more in writing the code to represent the equations and systems of equations than in actually solving them.

Any clues as to how to start writing our code would be a huge start!

[image: Morris-Lecar P1]
[image: Morris-Lecar P2]

In concrete terms, we don't know where to start with my working group, even for question 3.a..

We know that nullclines are associated with $dV/dt = 0$ and $dW/dt = 0$, which gives the following entries:

$W = \frac{I-g{Ca}M{\infty}(V)(V-V_{Ca})-g_L(V-V_L)}{g_K(V-VK)}$

$W = W{\infty}(V)$

But here for example, no idea how to write it on scilab, or how to display them graphically by varying I.

I hope the application is now clearer.

Appendix: scilab code.

```
E_L = -50;
E_Ca = 100;
E_K = -70;
V1 = -1.2;
V2 = 18;
V3 = 2;
V4 = 30;
g_L = 2;
g_Ca = 4.4;
g_K = 8.0;
C = 20;
gamma = 0.04;

minf(v)=.5(1+tanh((v-va)/vb))

winf(v)=.5(1+tanh((v-vc)/vd))

tauw(v)=1/cosh((v-vc)/(2*vd))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to make the question more to the point, but I think would be easier to answer if you would be even more specific.